Error when trying to debug with Go VS Code extension in windows
Im trying to set up the debugger in Visual Studio Code for a Go project on Windows 11, but I'm encountering an issue during the installation of the required extension.
When I open my Go project in VS Code and attempt to start debugging, I receive a recommendation to install the "delve" package, as shown in the image below:

But then the install fails as shown below

It seems that windows is not supported. I cannot find another extension for debugging go and windows and find it hard to believe it is not possible to debug go code on a windows device in vs code. But this is what the 'your_windows_architecture_is_not_supported_by_delve' error suggests.
I have tried the following steps to resolve the issue, but none of them have worked:
Restarting VS Code
Updating VS Code to the latest version
Disabling all other extensions
Reinstalling VS Code
I'm using:
OS: Windows 11
VS Code 1.89v
Can someone please help me understand why I cannot install this package and if there is another way to get a go debugger working in windows?
Thank you in advance for your assistance!

God thing the red line is there so I can't read AndrewJohnson, but please don't post images of text in general. What architecture go toolchain do you have installed?
